# No aparecen las opciones de Package Control en la paleta de comandos

Tags: sublimetext3, packages

tratando de desinstalar algunos paquetes que tenía, me encuentro con la sorpresa de que no me aparecen las opciones de `Package Control`. Al parece algunas de las últimas actualizaciones de Sublime Text rompió algo, no se está cargando el `Package Control` o no sé. La versión es `3.2.2, Build 3211`

Los paquetes que ya tengo insalados hace mucho y la barra de opciones que aparece vacía:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También me aparece que no puedo instalar nada desde la opción `Tools > Install Package Control...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La opción `Preferences > Package Control` está activada pero me da la paleta de comando vacía como en la primera imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No está en los paquetes ignorados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que tenía un archivo `email.py` (un script propio) metido entre los archivos de Sublime text dando el siguiente error en la consola del mismo editor:

```py
File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\email.py", line 29
    https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

una vez sacado el script, se ha cargado bien el `Control Package`, parece ser que cada vez que inicia Sublime Text ejecuta todos los scripts de python que se encuentren ahí metido.

Comment: si alguien desea que replique el error me avisan y muestro imagenes de la consola. No borre la pregunta debido a que puede ser algo que le ocurrar a alguien más, debido a lo común que te suele sugerir sublime text guardar un archivo no creado entre sus archivos de programa.